# printf formatting

Tags: c, string, printf

I want to use `printf` to display hex numbers in the form `0x###`, but if the number is 0, I want to omit the `0x` part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
printf("%#x", number);
```

Note that this does **exactly** what you want.  If the value of number is 0, it prints 0, otherwise it prints in hex.  Example:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 548548;

printf("%#x %#x\n", x, y);
```

Results in:

```
0 0x85ec4
```

Comment: It prints a upper-case X; the questioner requested a lower-case X.  I care; I like 0xABCDEF0123 notation.  But that's me being a fuss-pot.  Maybe using 'x' in place of 'X' would placate the questioner.

Comment: OK - fair enough.  I said I was being a fuss-pot.  I personally don't like the fact that to get the notation I prefer (lower case 0x, upper-case hex digits), I cannot use the standard printf() stuff; I have to write 0x%08lX or whatever; and that would not give 0 without the 0x part.

Comment: On the other hand, I find it irritating that I don't get the "0x" prefix if the value is zero, even though I'm asking for the dang prefix in general.  If I wanted zero to be a special case, I'd special case it. Then again, I don't find it to be a particularly big irritation.

Answer (score 4):

```
 printf ((x == 0) ? "%03x" : "0x%03x", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (num == 0)
{
     printf("0");
}
else
{
     printf("%X", num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it hard?

```
if number = 0
  printf without formatting
else
  printf with formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use an if statement to check if the number is 0 then figure out if you should print it as a 0x### or just 000 (or 0 if that was what you were looking for)